# Is my general formula for polynomial multiplication right?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Is the following equation for polynomial multiplication correct?

$
p(x)=p_{0} + \dots + p_{m}x^m \\
q(x)=q_{0} + \dots + q_{n}x^n \\
$

If $m \geq n$ then $i := m$. If $n \gt m$ then $i := n$.

$
p(x)q(x)=\sum_{j=0}^i p_{j} q_{i-j} x^j
$

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring) for the correct formula, $pq=s_{0}+s_{1}X+s_{2}X^{2}+\cdots +s_{l}X^{l}$.

Comment: Yep, the coefficient of the $i^{th}$ power is the sum of all contributions of the form $p_jq_{i-j}x^jx^{i-j}$.

Answer (score 18):

Using your notation, we know that the product $p(x)q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n+m$.

Hence one has $$p(x)q(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n+m} c_k x^k,$$
with coefficients $c_k$ to be determined.

Let $k \in \{ 0, \cdots, n+m \}$. Now the question is: how do you obtain terms in $x^k$ in the multiplication? Here are the ways to get some $x^k$, and we'll just have to add them altogether.

- multiply the constant term of $p$ by the term of degree $k$ of $q$ ;
- multiply the term of degree $1$ of $p$ by the term of degree $k-1$ of $q$ ;
- ...
- multiply the term of degree $j$ of $p$ by the term of degree $k-j$ of $q$ ;
- ...
- multiply the term of degree $k$ of $p$ by the constant term of $q$.

Therefore, one has

$$c_k = \sum_{i=0}^k p_i q_{k-i}$$
where $p_i$ (resp. $q_i$) denotes the $i$-th coefficient of $p$ (resp. $q$).

That gives us the general formula you're looking for:

$$ \bbox[lightgreen,5px,border:2px solid green]{\left( \sum_{i=0}^{\deg p} p_i x^i\right) \cdot \left( \sum_{j=0}^{\deg q} q_j x^j\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\deg p + \deg q} \sum_{l=0}^k p_l q_{k-l} x^k}.$$

Comment: The language herein is not clear enough. It is important to adapt from [1] and, ``Note that we treat $q_i$   as zero for   $i> \text{deg}\,q$ ... '' Similarly, we treat $p_i$   as zero for   $i> \text{deg}\,p$. Citation [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_arithmetic

Answer (score 3):

It is close.

$p(x)q(x)=\sum_\limits{i=0}^{m+n}\sum_\limits{j=0}^i p_{j} q_{i-j} x^i$

Comment: This formula is wrong

Comment: yes this is wrong because when i=m+n and j=0 there is no term of index m+n-0

Comment: @pHotone the formula is correct.

Comment: if q is maximum degree m or n, there is no term such $q_{m+n}$ in $q(x)$ in general.

Answer (score 0):

It is close.

$p(x)q(x)=\sum_\limits{k=0}^{m+n}x^k \sum_\limits{i=0...m, j=0...n}^{i+j=k} p_{i} q_{j} $