# Formula for product of two polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

I have found such a formula
$$
\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k \right)\cdot \left(\sum_{j=0}^m b_j z^j \right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n+m} \left( \sum_{j=k-\min(n,m)}^{\min(k,\max(n,m))}a_j b_{k-j} \right)z^k,
$$
but seems it's  too complicated. Is there any other formulas?

Comment: The inner sum corresponds to a convolution of the coefficients. You may simplify it by going in the frequency domain (Fourier) for example (or $z$ transform), but it is unlikely it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Damien Can you explane it as an asnwer?

Comment: I have no time now, sorry. You can find information on convolution here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution. It is a well known operation, widely studied. Used for example to represent filtering

Comment: Not sure why the answer in there is not correct but may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937543/is-my-general-formula-for-polynomial-multiplication-right

Answer (score 3):

You may simplify a little by omitting the extremes of summation.

Define $a_i=0$ if $i\not\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ and $b_j=0$ if $j\not\in\{0,1,\dots,m\}$.
Let $c_k$ be the coefficient of $z^k$ in the product. Then the formula is saying that
$$
c_k = \sum_{\substack{i,j\in\mathbb N\\i+j=k}} a_ib_j
= \sum_{i\in\mathbb N}a_i b_{k-i} .
$$
This is as simple as it gets.

This way you can extend the formula to [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series).