# proving ring of convergence $fg=\sum\limits_{m,n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n b_m (z-z_0)^{n+m}$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, laurent-series

how to prove this
[image]

I am stuck at this point
$$fg=\sum_{m,n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n b_m (z-z_0)^{n+m}=\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} c_i(z-z_0)^{2n}$$ what to do next ? anyone please help me in proving this

Comment: Next: collect all terms with the same power of $(z-z_0)$.  So, for each $k \in \mathbb Z$, what is the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^k$?

Comment: Please replace the image by text and $\LaTeX$. You are asked to express $fg$ as a Laurent series, so find $c_n$ such that $fg = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n (z-z_0)^n$.

Comment: The reason for a request such as this one from @Christoph is: an image cannot be found  by a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to write the series as $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n (z-z_0)^n$ and find $c_n$ (hint: they're given by infinite sums; it might help to first consider the finite case, then generalize). For the convergence, you might find that the following result helps:

> > **Proposition:** If $A=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \alpha_n$ and $B=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \beta_n$ both converge absolutely, then so does their product $AB.$

Comment: Have you considered the finite case? Do you know, for example, the general form of the product of two polynomials? If not, you should start there.

Comment: Here is a link for the product of two polynomials. What do you think the formula might generalize to in your case?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937543/is-my-general-formula-for-polynomial-multiplication-right

Comment: Do you have a proposal for the coefficients?

Comment: $c_0 = a_0b_0 , c_1 = a_0 b_1 + a_1b_0$ ?

Comment: Okay, so those are the first two coefficients for polynomials. You want the general formula. This is directly related, and immediately generalizes, to your coefficients, where the indices can now range over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: so this directly shows that it's convergence is in $r<|z-z_0|<R$ ? and kindly remove your previous comments... mathstack notitfied me just a while ago...

Comment: The proposition I listed does, yes. The previous discussion was only related to the closed-form expression of the coefficients.

Comment: this means ... if c_i can be expressed in terms of \sum a_nb_n then it also converges in the same ring ?

Comment: The proposition isn't directly related to the coefficients, it's related to the sums. For example, $A=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^n$ converges absolutely in $r<|z-z_0|<R$ by assumption, so here $\alpha_n= a_n (z-z_0)^n.$

Comment: Also, it means that if I have two sums that converge absolutely, then so does their product. Here we know both sums converge absolutely on $r<|z-z_0|<R.$