# $f: F[x] \to F[x]$ is a isomorphism if $F$ is a domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-homomorphism

Let $F$ be a field and $f: F[x] \to F[x]$ with $f\left(p\right) := p\left(ax\right)$. In fact, $f$ is a isomorphism and this is a elementary proof, with the "one-to-one" part of it just by showing that $f(g) = f(h) \Rightarrow g=h$ and the properties of a homomorphism did by using the identities of sum and product of polynomials (the last one was found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1937571).

Ok, now comes the question: If $F$ is, now, a domain, the result still true? Because in my proof I can't see any necessity of it been an field. If someone have some clue, I'll aprecciate!

Comment: Do you mean $F[x]$ all along - or otherwise: what is $F[X]$? Also, is $a\ne 0$? With that interpretation, it is not true as it is not a surjection if $a$ is not invertible. Take $F=\mathbb Z$ and $a=2$.

Comment: Yes, it its $F[x] \to F[x]$, was a typing error. Yes, $a \neq 0$. If I take those $F$ and $a$ wont be surjective because I'll only have even coefficients?

Comment: Exactly! (Except for the constant coefficient, all the other coefficients will be bound to be even.)

Comment: Frasing Stinking Bishops's point differently. If you denote that mapping by $f_a$ instead of just $f$, then the inverse is $f_a^{-1}=$_____?

Comment: It will be $f_{a}^{-1} \left( p \right)= p\left(a^{-1}x \right)$, right? So if $a$ is not an invertible number of $F$, it will not exist.

Comment: @GuilhermeNetto If $a$ is not invertible then this function is not well defined, but you still need to argue that no other function can work as he inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove the following more general result:

**Lemma** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Then $f: R[x] \to R[x]$ defined by $f(p)=P(aX)$ is an isomomorphism if and only if $a$ is invertible in $R$.

For the direct implication you can show that $g(P)=P(a^{-1}X)$ is the inverse.

For the inverse implication, use the fact that there exists some $P \in R[X]$ such that
$$f(P)=X$$